# WordPress localhost site redirect to live site

Tags: redirect

I have download the code and export the database from server and setup the site on my localhost also I have been changed the home and site URL in wp_options table I am able to login at wp-admin but when I am clicking on the home page it redirect me to live site.

If anyone know the issue please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you check your menu links or if the links are hard coded?

Comment: Yes I have checked its not static

Comment: Check htaccess for any redirect rules to live site

Comment: there was no .htacces I have put the htaccess but not working

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try following

- If there are caching plugins installed like W3 total cache. Then purge cache first. Or may be disable them for time being
- Perform Search and Replace in the database for Old Site URL. You can [Use this Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/)
- Reset Permalinks ( Dashboard >> Settings >> Permalinks )
- Last but not the least. Clear your browser Cache and History

  - In Chrome, you can try to [clear your DNS cache](https://superuser.com/a/203702/389865) before clearing *all* your cache

Comment: I have already done this and this works for me. Thanks

Comment: The Last option works for me :)

Comment: Last worked for me too - still don't get why that would happen!? :(

Comment: Glad it helped you. :)

Comment: I have tested and confirmed: in my case it was the browser's cache. I had done all previous steps to no avail and then moved to another browser to check. Done. It was cache.

Comment: 1- after delete w3 total cache 2- i reset permalinks then 3- open in incognito

Comment: Also be aware that if you have a Wordpress multisite then you need to follow additional steps, see: https://wpengine.com/support/how-to-change-a-multi-site-primary-domain/

Answer (score 17):

According to the wordpress [reference here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

Add these two lines to your wp-config.php, where "example.com" is the correct location of your site.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com'); 
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

OR

Edit functions.php

Add these two lines to the file, immediately after the initial "

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
```

Or check the `.htaccess` file as well if added any rewrite rule for redirect the website.

Hope this help!!

Comment: So, it's working or not?

Comment: not working but when I changed the permalink structure and then change back it to old one its working.

Comment: Great dude you have solved!!!

Comment: worked for me, but i also had to disable browser cache and add all of these together: `define('WP_HOME','http://localhost'); 
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost');
define('WP_CACHE', false);
define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

Comment: Thanks man!!!! This have helped me a lot!!!!!! Thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Had to change these lines in my wp-config.php from

```
define('WP_CACHE', true);
define( 'WPCACHEHOME', 'C:\wamp64\www\wp-content\plugins\wp-super-cache/' );
```

to

```
define('WP_CACHE', false);
//define( 'WPCACHEHOME', 'C:\wamp64\www\wp-content\plugins\wp-super-cache/' );
```

Comment: worked for me only after adding all of these and disabling browser cache: `define('WP_HOME','http://localhost'); 
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost');
define('WP_CACHE', false);
define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this problem by [installing WP cli](https://wp-cli.org/fr/#installation) and running :

`wp search-replace 'example.com' 'example.local'`

[Check the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#wp-cli) for more info. But as JItendra said, it's important to clear the browser cache too after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

you can change live url to local url directly in database table **wp_options** two **option_name** field

```
1) siteurl
2) home
```

After this save permalink.

Hope is useful

Comment: I have changed it already

Answer (score 0):

Try remove any redirecting plugins if you have in your live site codebase. I solved the same issue by removing the "safe-redirect-manager" plugin in local.

Answer (score -1):

I just change my permalink structure to plain and again to old one then Its working.
thanks all of you for your help. :)