# Wordpress keeps redirecting me to online site

Tags: domain, site-url

I need to create a copy of a WordPress in a local environment.

I have alread done some research and

1. Included the following line in wp-config.php (at it's start, also tried at the end)

   define('WP_SITEURL','http://mydomain.local');
   define('WP_HOME','http://mydomain.local');

Note sure if these URLs should be different.

2. Changed
   `siteurl` and `home` to http://mydomain.local in database in table [prefix]_options
3. I have also checked the .htaccess file and it contain nothing that refers to the online domain.

but it keeps redirecting me to the online domain.

Comment: Do you have anything in your htaccess file (redirects) or any sort of redirect plugin?

Comment: Good question, I had already checked .htaccess (but forgot it when writing my question), it has nothing that  refers to the online domain), regarding plug-ins, I guess I need to ask this to the person who administrated the WP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress localhost site redirect to live site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/263924/wordpress-localhost-site-redirect-to-live-site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear all rewrite_rules in the wp_options table in your database then open your local website in an incognito browser or clear your browser cache.

Comment: How do you clear rewrite rules?

Comment: Go to your database in PHPMYADMIN go to wp_options find rewrite_rules and delete all the values out of it

Comment: That's the first thing I tried, I just don't see anything called "rewrite_rules"

Comment: There’s multiple pages of fields in wp_options check the box to show all and then search for rewrite_rules