# WordPress localhost site always redirect to live site

Tags: redirect, migration, cache, localhost, export

I know that there is already a [similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/263924/wordpress-localhost-site-redirect-to-live-site) like this. But I have already done all these suggested solution and nothing works for me.

- If there are caching plugins installed like W3 total cache. Then purge cache first. Or may be disable them for time being

  - I have already disabled any possible plugin that using cache or redirection ]
- Perform Search and Replace in the database for Old Site URL. You can Use this Plugin .

  - I opened sql file and perform search and replace for the live url into my local url ]
- Reset Permalinks ( Dashboard >> Settings >> Permalinks ).

  - I used wp cli to perform permalinks reset ]
- Last but not the least. Clear your browser Cache and History

  - Always clearing my browser and even using incognito ]

When I deleted all the existing tables, wordpress asking me to setup new wordpress but when I put the tables back, still redirecting me to the live site. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Look in your `wp_options` database table for the `siteurl` and `home` options and check these are using your local URL.

As Captain S commented, these can also be overridden in your wp-config:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.localsite.test');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.localsite.test');
```

Comment: Yes, when I did a search and replace of my sql file, these values on my database has been changed as well

Comment: Can you please rename your plugins directory so that all plugins are disabled. Do you have any other rewrite rules in your htaccess or Apache vhost?

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. I already figured out why. The one who made the project put a redirection code on the theme itself.

Answer (score 0):

check your wp-config.php if you have defined 'WP_HOME' and/or 'WP_SITEURL'. Setting these values will override the wp_options table values. If that doesn't help I recommend the tool [database search and replace](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes,  I have already defined this on my wp-config.php

define('WP_CACHE', false);
define('WP_HOME','http://local.test'); 
define('WP_SITEURL','http://local.test');

-- I'll try to use the tool you recommend. Thanks

Comment: I've tried the tool and no luck, still redirecting me to the live url. And I have only a basic .htaccess
`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/culinary/
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`

I'm running out of options here. and so behind of the project. Could anyone help me with this please. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Someone put a redirection code on the theme itself